# If a model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, how should ViewModel register/deregister for PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Model which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it may get updated by a background business thread. Its related ViewModel also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. And their View obviously binds to ViewModel. This View may be shown on multiple places, and my goal is that all of them get updated when the model changes.

I know that ViewModel should register for `PropertyChanged` event of Model. But I don't know when and where is the best place for this registering and deregistering. Specially about the deregistering, since I'm scared of having hundreds of VM event handlers on the Model for the VM/views that are not shown anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it an absolute necessity for you to limit the View not directly bind to the Model?

You can expose the Model as a property on the VM and then have your View directly bind to it thereby not having the VM subscribe to INPC from Model

something like:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
...

private MyModel _model;
public MyModel Model {
  get {
    return _model;
  }
  set {
    if (value == _model)
      return;
    value = _model;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Model);
  }
}
...

}
```

and in xaml (when `MyViewModel` is the `DataContext`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.ModelProperty}" />
```

**Update:**

Maybe this is of some help for tapping into the `PropertyChanged` events of Models in a "weak" fashion

[IWeakEventListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iweakeventlistener.aspx)

> Using the central event dispatching of a WeakEventManager enables the handlers for listeners to be garbage collected (or manually purged) even if the source object lifetime extends beyond the listeners.

which is used in

[Josh Smith's PropertyObserver](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/)

This should hopefully solve your issue of needing to explicitly un-register?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think it is necessary. Since I have to manipulate the data of the Model to be able to be bound easily and clean.

Comment: manipulate the data of the Model where? in the VM? that's not really a good practice either. You should manipulate the data of the Model in the Model if so or if it's a manipulation just for the View rendering, it should be in a Converter.

Comment: Yes, I meant some view rendering kind of thing. The rendering is kinda complicated which is not just a single property-to-property mapping, that I can use a Converter.

Comment: Well use a MultiBinding then. Don't know how it's so complicated that binding to a VM property solves it when directly binding to the Model cannot. they are both in the end single properties. Only your binding source object changes. Am sorry without knowing exactly what your trying to achieve it's hard to convince that it "can" be done with a Model binding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Think of the Model like as a Contact. The contact has a list of ContactDetails. (Classes inherited from ContactDetail like FirstNameDetail, LastNameDetail, ImageDetail, PhoneDetail, MobileDetail, ...)

Now the ViewModel extracts some of these like FirstName and LastName and builds a new property FullName, and filters these details from the list and shows the other detail on a list.
We have a TextBox for FullName and a list for other details.
Do you think this can be done by converters?

Comment: ok that's good info. So your View renders this Contact in a particular way based on the info it has from the Model? Using a MultiBinding with a converter should achieve this. Don't get me wrong, I'm not against you subscribing to the Model from the VM but I'm just trying to explain that you can do what you require binding directly with the Model and using MultiBinding & Converter to help the View render it's requirements, that way only the view and it's helpers deal with the render and not the Model or VM.

Comment: I understand that. How can you split a TextBox text into two properties (say FirstName and LastName) by MultiBinding and Converters? Problem becomes more complicated when these are not properties but items of an array.

BTW, do you have any idea of how is the best way to register and deregister VM into a Model which implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Viv However, using your approach, we end up having 398573987 single-use converters in the solution, whereas I really prefer to keep converters as reusable and generic as possible (`BoolToVisibilityConverter`, `EnumToBoolConverter`, etc)

Comment: I thought you already have FirstNameDetail and LastNameDetail from the Model and your getting your View to concatenate it. For this very thing you could just have `<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0},{1}"><Binding Path="Model.FirstName" /><Binding Path="Model.FirstName" /></MultiBinding>`. Not sure about the best way to subscribe to the Model from the VM soz

Comment: @HighCore Well the level of specific detail you give a converter is upto you. You can make your converter generic enough to not have a million converters. It really depends on your use case. Ofc having a million converters is pointless. I don't think I've got a million converters. If you have different Text format bindings, Have your String format as a Binding parameter and that saves you a 100000 converters and so on. Make it generic!!

Comment: @Viv yeah, but you're talking about Model-specific converters. We have 360+ different entities in our data model, I don't think that's an option. Also for the regular `StringFormat` case it's ok, but then there's a lot of business-rule dependent stuff that would be happening in converters. Something I don't really like at all.

Comment: @HighCore I agree with you completely abt over-using Converters which can be said abt anything in programming all together(function overloading, default arguments, exception specification...). Also I'm not advocating for Model specific converters. If they are generic enough they can be used anywhere you desire fit. Here it would just happen to be for the Model.Also IMO the view is just a representation of the data the user see's. Any business rule dependent stuff should be handled right in the model itself before being exposed as a property and letting the view / converter manipulate it.

Comment: @n0ne I've updated my answer with something I found on Josh Smith's blog that might be of help to your issue. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around this issue by hooking in to model events on load and removing them on unloaded, the problem here is that the view model can miss events if it's off the screen. I usually just refresh the data quickly on load.

OnLoad - Refresh the VM data from the model and hook events.
OnUnLoad - remove any hooks that you've put in place.

Comment: Good idea! But what if the item is off the screen on Unload? The VM will miss it and the event hooks remain there for ever...

Comment: The unload event will most likely fire as the item goes off the screen but even if it stays loaded, at some point it will get unload called when it's no longer required.

Comment: @Andy if something is subscribing to your object's events (like INPC) it will never ever get garbage collected -- Why not just use WeakEvents?