# Notifying ViewModel of Property change from Model class

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, wpf-controls

In my WPF application, I have my TreeView IsSelected property binded to a property in my Model class. So the selected Item is set in the Model class. I need to notify my ViewModel whenever the selected Item is set/changed. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the "Update" part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16341172/1834662). [Josh Smith's PropertyObserver](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/) is great if the Model property complies with INPC. If it doesn't implement INPC, have your View's `SelectedItem` property bound to the VM instead of the Model and in the property setter update the Model from the VM.

Comment: If you want to notify to the viewmodel about your propertychange you need to bind to the property present in viewmodel or you can simply make another property and assign your model property to that viewModel property so that everytime you select your viewmodel property change will raise..

Comment: I can't bind to the Property present in ViewModel. both my Model and ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChange class. Can I use that somehow?
    `OnPropertyChange("PropertyName")`
PropertyName is in ViewModel but my Model does not raise that property may be because it fails to locate the property. Any Idea?

Comment: @WQad did you check the `PropertyObserver` class I linked? Since you mention your Model implements INPC, that's the cleanest approach I can think of with weak-dependency between the VM and the Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your Model instance is part of your ViewModel... First, yes it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If you also want your ViewModel to get notified, then you ViewModel should subscribe to that event.

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _name;
   public string Name {
      get {return _name;}
      set {
         _name = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
   }
// etc... including INPC implementation
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
   public ViewModel (Model model){
      this.MyModel = model;
      this.MyModel.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => { DoSomething();};
   }

   public Model MyModel { get; set; }
}
```